# NaN values in tensorflow when running from GPU and using multiple threads to feed queues

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, gpu

I'm running into NaN values in a model I'm training.

I have 2 tensorflow queues. The first is being fed by an independent loader thread, a second thread is reading from the first queue, performing preprocessing, and loading into the second queue.

That all occurs on the CPU. Then the model reads a batch from the second queue and trains on the GPU.

I get NaNs after a variable number of steps, usually on the order of 10-20.

I can side step the problem in 2 ways:

1. Run on the CPU. Same code runs fine on the CPU.
2. Remove threading, same code, instead of running the loader and preprocessor in a thread, just do those two steps in sequence before the training step.

So the problem is only encountered when I run with multiple threads accessing the queues from different devices.

Or so it seems, I've thus far failed to distill the problem into a minimal test case successfully. A simplified test of this seems to work.

Wondering if there are any known related issues.

I've reproduced this on 2 systems one running TF 1.0.1 and one running 1.1.0-rc1. I've tried both CUDNN 5 and CUDNN 6 libraries.

Comment: I still haven't successfully reproduced this issue in a limited test case, but it appears to be that I had attached some image preprocessing ops to the GPU, but I was feeding them from cpu based queues. This didn't cause a failure, but I got weird numerical instability and eventually NaNs. I could solve the problem as mentioned above, running on the GPU without threads/queues, run entirely on the CPU, or my final solution: pin the image processing ops to the CPU using `with Device('/cpu:0'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appeared to be related to having some of the `tf.image` processing functions defined on the GPU, but feeding them data from a queue on the CPU. I wouldn't have expected that to be a problem, but as soon as I tied those operations to the CPU using everything worked fine.